# Debugging wp_query orderby for taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, order, sql, debug

I cannot seem to find where WP_Query adds the orderby clause to a SQL query.

I am using this code:

```
function wpd_team_taxonomy_queries( $query ) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_tax( 'team' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby',  " SUBSTRING_INDEX( t.name, ' ', -1 ) "); 
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
}add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_team_taxonomy_queries' );
```

This works well apart from one particular taxonomy type, which I am debugging. I can see that WP_Query orderby parameter is set as above, but I cannot see in any of the queries from the DEBUG plugin or the Query Monitor plugin where the `SUBSTRING_INDEX( t.name, ' ', -1 )` code is added to a SQL query.

Neither for the correctly ordering results nor the one that is not ordered.

How would I find where this particular SQL query is built for orderby to debug this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass SQL directly as query parameters. The only valid values for `orderby` are covered in [the docs for `WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).

If you want to directly modify the SQL, you need to use the `posts_*` filters, in this case [`posts_orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby).

Comment: Thanks Milo. I did that and it's working. The original code was a cut and paste from stack overflow. I wonder if orderby accepted SQL in times past.